# read a id from Request.QueryString

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

hello im tying to read id from Request.QueryString in html tage in asp.net but it can work and read a velue by Request.QueryString from url. here is a code which i used below

```
<video src='<%# "VideoHandler.ashx?id=" + Request.QueryString["id"] ' width="220" 
height="200" controls="" preload=""></video>
```

please let me know how can i bid this in fount hand tag in asp.net

Comment: Where are you closing <%# tag? It needs to be closed with %>.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to close your server tag

```
<video src='<%# "VideoHandler.ashx?id=" + Request.QueryString["id"] %>' width="220" 
height="200" controls="" preload=""></video>
```

Second...

I've always found it easier to add this to a protected function in the code behind and call the function in the mark up.

So (assuming c#) I would have

```
protected string getHandler(){
     return "VideoHandler.ashx?id=" + Server.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["id"]);
}
```

Then in the markup just have

```
<video src='<%# getHandler() %> ' width="220" 
height="200" controls="" preload=""></video>
```

Comment: +0. Please edit your post to remove/fix XSS issue. This is not ideal answer for SO so far.

Comment: I'm missing the XSS issue.  Although, I would love to know what it is so I don't suggest it again.

Comment: Cross site scripting - what if query string contains something like (properly encoded) `id="><script>alert("HaHa")</script>`. One never should put input from user directly into HTML without proper encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close your server side tag and you shouldn't have your string in your tag.  src property should look like so:

```
VideoHandler.ashx?id=<%# Request.QueryString["id"] %>
```

Comment: +0. While ok answer to immediate issue, posting answer with XSS  is not good.